# How do I prove this identity on $n!-1$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Set $n \ge 1$. Prove that $$n!-1 = \sum_{X \in \{1,2,...,n-1\}^P} \prod_{y \in X} y.$$

I found this one while studying my combinatorics lecture notes. Intuitively, $n!-1=(1+1)\cdot(2+1)\cdots(n-1+1)-1$. Expand and it looks like the resulting sum of products. I tried to prove this identity using induction but it somehow got very complicated.

Remark: $P=$ powerset.

Comment: You're on the right track. You merely have to prove "Expand and it looks like the resulting sum of products". However, this may be simpler than you imagine...(Think of Vieta's Formula)

Comment: Why the $-1$? The sum equals $n!$. It seems the setters are ignoring the empty set.

Comment: It is generally noted $X\in\mathcal P(\{1,2,..,n-1\})$ for powerset, so that we do not confuse and get result $P\times(n-1)!$

Comment: @zwim In fact it has many notations, for example $2^{\{1,\ldots,n-1\}}$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) lists even more, though they are variants of your notation.

Comment: @Yuval Maybe but for me it would be easier to do math using my french words, but I use english terms so that most of SE people understand, I think it goes along with the notations, better use the more widely accepted ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this by induction (with $n!-1$ replaced by $n!$). The idea is that
$$
\sum_{X \in \{1,\ldots,n\}^P} f(X) = \sum_{X \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}^P} [f(X) + f(X \cup \{n\})].
$$
In your case $f(X)$ is the product of all elements in $X$ (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Think about the polynomial $\prod_{i=1}^n(x+i)$.  In expanding each factor in the product, you have to choose either an $x$ or a number. So,
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n(x+i)=\sum_{X\subseteq
\{1,\ldots,n\}}x^{n-|A|}\prod_{y\in X}y.$$
Your result follows by letting $x=1$.